# Trying to print multiple result set .But list returns only object

Tags: java, hibernate

This my query which i am trying get result from multiple table.

```
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select t.id as ID,
                                                    t.companyname as COMPANYNAME,
                                                    e.fullname as FULLNAME,
                                                    e.empid as EMPID,
                                                    ca.dateallocated as DATEALLOCATED 
                                             from   bw_tempclientdetails t,
                                                    bw_employee_details e,
                                                    bw_clientallocation ca 
                                             where  e.empid=ca.empid and                                       
                                                    ca.companyname=t.companyname ");
```

But query.list returns only object in which i am unable to convert to string representation. Any solution?

Comment: As far as i know, all Object in Java has a toString() method

Answer (score 0):

You can create a POJO. A little class like:

```
/**
* Dto.
*/
class MyClass {
    int id;
    String companyName;
    String fullName;
    int empId;
    Date dateAllocated;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    public MyClass(int id, String companyName, String fullName, int empId, Date dateAllocated) {
        this.id = id;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.dateAllocated = dateAllocated;
    }
    // Rest of code
}
```

Doing so `Hibernate` allows you to instantiate one Object per row returned. So a full list with the results.

If some elements are nullable then you better use Objects (`Integer` instead of  `int`).

To instantiate objects:

```
select new package.MyClass(colA, colB...)
```

In our example

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select new a.b.MyPojo(t.id as ID,
                                                t.companyname as COMPANYNAME,
                                                e.fullname as FULLNAME,
                                                e.empid as EMPID,
                                                ca.dateallocated as DATEALLOCATED)
                                         from   bw_tempclientdetails t,
                                                bw_employee_details e,
                                                bw_clientallocation ca 
                                         where  e.empid=ca.empid and                                       
                                                ca.companyname=t.companyname ");
```

Would return a `List<MyPojo>` with one element per row. Is that what you want?

Udo.

Comment: can u please explain this shortly how to get all the result set values.I am not sound in hibernate .

Comment: hi i tried your solution but i am getting this exception .          Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.bluewhale.model.TestPojo(t.id as ID,t.companyname as COMPANYNAME,e.fullname as ' at line1                                                                   But when i execute the sql alone on mysql shell it shows the result.what may be wrong? is very to tough to get result set values...?